# Estimating running time for large inputs

Tags: runtime, complexity-theory

An algorithm having worst-case running time of O(N^2) took 30secs to run for input size N=20. How long will the same algorithm take for input size N=400 ?

Comment: 1) Please mark homework with the [homework] tag.  2) Please multiply and post the result you got so we can comment on your answer.  This is not `www.do_my_homework_for_me.com`

Comment: **Asymptotic** behavior says nothing of the time taken for particular values of `N`. If you were to unroll the definitions of the mathematic concepts involved far enough, you would get something like "forall epsilon, there exists N such that …". If the teacher who gave you this homework didn't tell you what epsilon 20 was the N of, he didn't give you the necessary information to answer the question. Or perhaps he did, and he expects the answer "It is not possible to tell".

Comment: This isn't homework. I came across this question while preparing for interviews and wanted to know the validity of such a question, hence decided to turn to the best programmer resource I know of - stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O(n^2) implies proportionality to the square of n (see [this guide](http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/)). So

```
 T = K (n^2)
30 = K (20^2)
 K = 30 / 400
```

Hence time for 400 items

```
   = (30 / 400)( 400 ^ 2 )
```

So that 12000 seconds.

Now, that's not necessarily true unless you know that the original 20 item test was a worst case scenario, if it isn't then we have a bad estimate of K. Even if if we have a good estimate of K so we we know the worst case scenarion for 400 items, we don't know that these 400 items will take that long.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it just helps establish an upper bound on the running time.

Comment: Note my point about the original "20 takes 30 seconds" datum. Unless there is some reason to know that this *is* a worst case input set you have not actually established an upper bound.

Comment: Ahh, didn't think about that. Thanks, I've got some clarity now, it was easy for me to miss that point.